# Switch statements in Rock-Paper-Scissors game

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I am very much new to design pattern. I'm trying to modify the Rock, paper, scissor game from an example book where I try to add more various design pattern. But I am encountering two similar switch statement which I think have duplicates and I don't have any idea on removing those duplicates.

A abstract class:

```
abstract class UserVsComp {
    protected static Item item;
    abstract protected Item getItem() throws WrongMove;
}
```

Here are the two switch statement:(First Class is for user movement)

```
class UserMove extends UserVsComp {
    private String move;
    public UserMove(String move) { this.move = move; }
    public Item getItem() throws WrongMove {
        switch (choiceValue(this.move)) {
            case 0 :  item = new Paper(); break;
            case 1 :  item = new Scissors(); break;
            case 2 :  item = new Rock(); break;
            default:  throw new WrongMove("Wrong move. Game end");
        }
    return item;
}
```

Second class is for Computer movement:

```
class ItemGenerator extends UserVsComp {
    public Item getItem() throws WrongMove {
        switch((int) (Math.random() * 2)) {
            case 0: item = new Paper(); break;
            case 1: item = new Scissors(); break;
            case 2: item = new Rock(); break;
            default:  throw new WrongMove("Wrong move. Game end");
        }
    return item;
    }
}
```

The two switch statement have same case (I guess duplicacy). I'd like to know if there is any way to remove this duplicacy.

Comment: Another problem (not related to your question, but this is Code Review): all the subclassing is an abuse of inheritance and probably should be done with composition. ItemGenerator and UserMove are subclasses of UserVsComp, which doesn't make sense to me. Could you please cite the book, so we can have more context?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes you are right. This is a mistake I have made. Actually the `ItemGenerator` class will be `CompMove` class. Thanks for pointing that out and I will try to use composition instead of inheritance in this example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of creating a new Item each time you can just use a enum:

```
public enum Move{
    Paper{ 
        public boolean canBeat(Move other){
            return other==Rock;
        }
    },
    Scissor{ 
        public boolean canBeat(Move other){
            return other==Paper;
        }
    },
    Rock{ 
        public boolean canBeat(Move other){
            return other==Scissor;
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean canBeat(Move other);


    public boolean losesTo(Move other){
        return other.canBeat(this);
    }
}
```

Then You can keep them in an array (like what is returned by `Move.values()`) and index into that.

```
public Item getItem() throws WrongMove {
    int choice = choiceValue(this.move);
    if(choice<0||choice >= Move.values().length)
        throw new WrongMove("Wrong move. Game end");
    else return  Move.values()[choice];
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use `enum`. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 8):

This is a quite easy fix. All you need to do is to extract a method.

Both snippets have the same input: `int`

Both snippets have the same output: `Item`

Both snippets can throw the same exception: `WrongMove`

Put this method somewhere:

```
public static Item itemForInt(int value) throws WrongItem {
    switch(value) {
        case 0: return new Paper();
        case 1: return new Scissors();
        case 2: return new Rock();
        default:  throw new WrongMove("Wrong move. Game end");
    }
}
```

And call it from your other methods.

```
class UserMove extends UserVsComp {
    private String move;
    public UserMove(String move) { this.move = move; }
    public Item getItem() throws WrongMove {
        return SomeClass.itemForInt(choiceValue(this.move)));
    }
}
```

---

`WrongMove` would be better named `WrongMoveException`

The `getItem()` method should be marked with `@Override` in `UserMove` and `ItemGenerator`

There is no need to put this on a single line:

```
public UserMove(String move) { this.move = move; }
```

This is more readable:

```
public UserMove(String move) {
    this.move = move;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.The answer is very helpful and easy way to do it. Thanks.